# Gujarati Font Rendering

Tags: android, typeface

I am having sqlite database containing gujarati words..

The sql query for the database is...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE eng_guj (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, eng_word , guj_word );
INSERT INTO eng_guj VALUES(1,'aardvark','ઊધઇ ખાનારું આફ્રિકાનું એક નિશાચર સસ્તન પ્રાણી.');
COMMIT;
```

I want to display the text in textview.. but its not rendering properly.. meant Its displaying the word in gujarati like "આફ્રિકા" will be displayed as "આફરિકા".

I already have used Typeface and different ttf fonts.

[image]

Comment: Hi...you better always try to use prepared statements for insert and fetch statements,because the above steps may cause problems on sometimes.

Comment: @vishal, did you get a solution for this problem?

Comment: @Rajnikant no man.. not yet :(

Comment: @Vishal i am not getting gujrati text in my application. i am using TypeFace to set gujrati but its not work. so can you explain me how to set gujrati text? thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the same error. So the error is reproducible. I tried to render Gujarati font using WebView but with no success. However, it works with TextView using certain fonts such as aakar-medium.ttf and Rekha.ttf (Both can be found [here](http://www.utkarsh.org/Download)). However, I am still getting the error mentioned in this post. I think a work-around would be writing a similar algorithm as given on this link - See the source code given at http://anubadok.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/anubadok/branches/android/. I am writing a similar algo and if I get it working - I will post it here.

Comment: Hi vishal, I see this application in android market, I done so many try to show the Gujarati in Emulator, But i failed,

Can you explain me please, how you done this in emulator ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This implies that your UI framework is handling "Complex text layout" properly or it is not configured properly to handle right.

Devanagari scripts, require different contextual shapes and ordering in text, which require complex layout support with Unicode characters. see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_text_layout)

A forum [here](http://www.androidquestions.org/threads/56-Complex-script-rendering-on-Android-phones) mentions that Android still doesn't have proper support to do this. But my information on this is limited.

Dipan.

Answer (score 1):

i have found that it's problem with android phone only, above 2.3 it's working fine

so build your apps with above android version 2.3

it will work sure for all android version above 2.3

like in AndroidManifest.xml file android:minSdkVersion should be more than 10,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: You are the person who made Koza! It's really nice dictionary i have seen, Thank you so much sir i am using it from one year thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you.
I downloaded the Shruti Font [here](http://www.fileden.com/files/2012/1/27/3255714/Gujarati%20fonts.rar).

Then using this code display the Gujarati font:

```
txtHeading=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeading);
            Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "SHRUTI.TTF");
            txtHeading.setTypeface(typeface);
txtHeading.setText("StackOverFlow પર આપનું સ્વાગત છે.");
```